# CCLabelTTF working in simulator but not in device

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

this code is working in simulator. when we load into the device it is not working.In console it is showing error as: 
`Unable to load font BARBATRI.ttf`

My code is:-

```
CCLabelTTF *score = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score : %d",[CommonUserDetails sharedUserDetails].GameScore] fontName:@"BARBATRI.ttf" fontSize:18];
score.position = ccp(240,160);
score.anchorPoint  = ccp(0.5, 0.5);
[self addChild:score];
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this font to your project resources and to your info.plist file to "Fonts provided by application" section. It is possible, that you have this font in Mac OS, but there is no such font in iOS.

Comment: no problem. you can mark answer as correct to help find it for anybody else =)